# TypeError: 'float' object is not callable in for loop declaration

Tags: python, list, for-loop, floating-point, typeerror

I'm attempting to display an `.obj` file in the console, and ran into a strange issue where a TypeError popped up for a `for` loop declaration that I had previously used, word for word. I can't seem to find the cause of this error.

```
vertices = [[2.4,5.6,2.1],[54.3,67.1,90.8],[21.9,73.5,12.3]]
def main():
  vertMinX = minmax(vertices, False)
  vertRangeX = minmax(vertices, True)-vertMinX
  for i in range(len(vertices)):
    print(1)
  normalize(vertices,vertMinX,vertRangeX)
  
def minmax(data, max):
  n=0
  val = data[0][n]
  if max:
    for i in range(len(data)):
      if val < data[i][n]:
        val = data[i][n]
  else:
    for i in range(len(data)):
      if val > data[i][n]:
        val = data[i][n]
  return val

def normalize(data, min, range):
  for i in range(len(data)):
    print(1)
main()
```

returns

```sh
1
1
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 25, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 7, in main
    normalize(vertices,vertMinX,vertRangeX)
  File "main.py", line 23, in normalize
    for i in range(len(data)):
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Comment: you used `range` as a parameter `def normalize`, which overrides the `range` function.

Comment: @MarkTolonen dont know how i didnt see that, thanks

Comment: `min` and `max` are also built-in functions that shouldn't be used as variable names as well.  You can use them instead of the `minmax` function.

Comment: @MarkTolonen yeah, I should change those names, but the built in wont work with full code, this is just a trimmed down version